# How to set a message payload to a apache camel rest request

Tags: rest, apache-camel

I need to set a JSON content as the message payload of a apache camel rest request. I tried it as follows. But it doesn't work.

```
<rest path="/service" consumes="application/json" produces="application/json">

        <put type="com.xxxx.yyyyy.esb.models.UserServiceMapping"
            uri="/create">
            <route>
                <log message="${body.serviceUrl}" />
                <log message="${body.mappedServiceObject}" />
                <log message="${body.systemUserDetails.userName}" />
                <log message="${body.systemUserDetails.password}" />
                <setBody> <simple>{"${body.mappedServiceObject}":{"userName" : 
                    "${body.userName}", "password" : "${body.password}"}} </simple> </setBody>
                <setHeader headerName="CamelRestletLogin">
                    <simple>admin</simple>
                </setHeader>
                <setHeader headerName="CamelRestletPassword">
                    <simple>admin</simple>
                </setHeader>

                <to
                    uri="restlet:http://xxx.xxx.x.xx:8081/xxxxxx/services/yyyyyyy/V1.0/users/create?restletMethod=POST" />
            </route>
        </put>
    </rest>
```

Comment: It doesn't work in what way?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. When I send the request as above none of errors occurred but in the tcp dump message body part is empty

Comment: @Souciance Eqdam Rashti If you requred I can send you the tcpdump

Comment: Have you tried something small first? LIke {"${body.mappedServiceObject}"} to see if this works? If not, does the body actually contain what you are referring to?

Comment: @Souciance Eqdam Rashti Yes, I tried. Body actually contains those data. <log message="${body.mappedServiceObject}" /> prints what I need.